# Why does my Android Studio 2.0 uses SDK 23 to compile all the time even when I use lower versions

Tags: android-studio

How to change the compile version to sdk 22 without getting errors about appcompat-v7:23.0.0 ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't... appcompat-v7:**23**.0.0 NEEDS SDK 23.

It's: SDK 22 OR appcompat-v7:23.0.0

*edit, but with this you can set the SDK compartible to what you might need: (does this makes sense?)

gradle.build(Module: app)

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.appname"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
}
```

Comment: How to use sdk 22 instead of appcompat-v7 ?
As i keep getting confused a lot.
I am new to android development and 
In the tutorial videos they extend Activity where as in compile sdk 23 uses AppCompatActivity and several such differences.